# How to display multiple resultset of a dataset in textbox

Tags: ssrs-2008

In one of my report datset returns more than one output for a query since the ouptut will be displayed in textbox where it can fetch more than one row report is getting failed. can someone help me on this. can we use listbox to overcome this problem .iam using ssrs 2008.
Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't have the results display in a table? You could even add a filter to the table to limit the results if needed.

Comment: Thank you let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

A Table control, or a List (which is, technically, just another table) should work just fine.